# Cycles 'vector' pass meaning of W, X, Y, Z

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine

I have a scene with moving objects and I want to extract the optical flow (apparent motion as seen by the camera). I am using Cycles. I include the 'Vector' pass and save the result as 'OpenEXR MultiLayer'. When I open the resulting file in Python I get the following channels:

- RenderLayer.Vector.W
- RenderLayer.Vector.X
- RenderLayer.Vector.Y
- RenderLayer.Vector.Z

What is the convention here? Could you provide a source for the information?

Comment: R: pixel displacement in X from current frame to previous frame
G: pixel displacement in Y from current frame to previous frame
B: pixel displacement in X from current frame to next frame
A: pixel displacement in Y from current frame to next frame. – From https://blenderartists.org/t/nuke-and-blender-speed-vector-pass-in-nuke/622902  - Maybe the info in this thread is helpful to do more research. RGBA might map to WXYZ or XYZW. (Not a real answer, so just commenting here.)

Comment: @micaelh Thank you, this information helped me to build the experiments that led to the actual answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guided by [@micaelh in the comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/216103/cycles-vector-pass-meaning-of-w-x-y-z#comment365162_216103), I ended up doing some experiments moving objects in a controlled way, the results are below.

- `Vector.X` - X displacement from previous frame to *current* frame
- `Vector.Y` - Y displacement from previous frame to *current* frame
- `Vector.Z` - X displacement from current frame to *next* frame
- `Vector.W` - Y displacement from current frame to *next* frame

Values are in pixels. X displacement is positive to the left, Y displacement is positive downwards.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain optical flow between frames t and t + k where k > 1? Thanks!