# Can Cycles' Vector Pass + Vector Blur node be used to create "smear" (instead of motion blur)?

Tags: compositing-nodes, vector, motion-blur, npr

Can the Cycles **Vector Pass** in conjunction with the **Vector Blur** compositor node be used to create "smear" instead of motion blur?

To be clear, by "smear" I mean this sort of distortion representing between-frame motion in traditional hand-drawn animation:

[image]

<sup>[Source: TraditionalAnimation.com](https://www.traditionalanimation.com/2017/smear-speed-motion-blur-effects-in-animation/)</sup>

This would be for adding a more hand-painted feel to non-photorealistic renders.

I have tried a few different approaches (which I might post detail on at a later time if it seems it would help)... but I have not yet achieved any usable results.

Maybe a different approach is needed (and I'm getting more ideas to try as I compose this question).

I'm curious what the community might come up with.

---

**Update:** I've got the motion vectors *displacing* the image. So this is the basic idea.

[image: experimental motion vector node setup]

It is having an effect, but it's not so accurate... yet. Maybe with some tweaking it will work. I need to study more closely how the mapping of the Vector pass works.

I don't think I'm supposed to just be *adding* the two sets of XY vectors together. But this was a quick way to verify that there is an affect.

[Related reading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/216368/2952)

Comment: I think animating actual geometry would be way more flexible approach. This is stylised look after all so it probably needs more artistic attention than some automatic post processing effect.

Comment: FWIW in the animation jargon this is called "Exaggerated Motion" and it's one of the famous 12 principles of animation. Since it's by design not physically based (it doesn't respect the preservation of volume), this will be hard if not impossible to achieve without manual tweaking I think :)